# .htaccess redirect all URLs and migrate domain.com/xyz to xyz.com

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm migrating a sub-site to its new domain and would like to redirect all the existing links to the new domain, while keeping all of the URL parameters

Examples:

```
domain.com/xyz --> xyz.com
domain.com/xyz/link.php --> xyz.com/link.php
domain.com/xyz/folder/link.php --> xyz.com/folder/link.php
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in the beginning of your htaccess (in document root folder of `domain.com`) just below `RewriteEngine On` line (or `RewriteBase` if present)

```
RewriteRule ^(xyz)(.*)$ http://$1.com$2 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^example/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

(Note that SO doesn't let me use xyz)